# How to create a scope to sort by FavoritePhoto id: in a has_many/through model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have models Favorite_Photo, User, and Photo

In Heroku Console:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.favorites.last 
=> #<Photo id: 37, user_id: 1, picture: "th.jpeg", title: "Cookies & Cream Pocky ", description: nil, photo_type: nil, location_type: nil, remote_picture_url: nil, created_at: "2016-07-07 03:04:03", updated_at: "2016-07-07 03:04:03">
```

And If I query:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.favorite_photos.last
=> #<FavoritePhoto id: 87, photo_id: 12, user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-07-07 19:37:28", updated_at: "2016-07-07 19:37:28">
```

class User

```
has_many :favorite_photos
has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_photos, source: :photo
```

class Photo

```
has_many :favorite_photos
has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_photos, source: :user
```

class FavoritePhoto

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :photo
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { 
scope: [:photo_id],
message: 'can only favorite an item once'
}
```

UsersController

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @favorites = @user.favorites
end
```

This returns a list of favorites ordered by photo_id. I want to create a scope that will order the favorites based on `FavoritePhoto id:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :favorites, -> { order("favorite_photos.id ASC") }, through: :favorite_photos, source: :photo
```

reference: [scopes for has_many](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many)